# Server not receiving JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, http, knockout.js

I have the following viewModel:

```
public class ProfileLocalizationViewModel
{
    public ProfileViewModel Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

with the `Profile` object looking like:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOutlet { get; set; }
    public bool IsWholesaler { get; set; }
    public bool IsProducer { get; set; }
    public List<ProfileLocalizationViewModel> Localizations { get; set; }
}
```

From the client, I'm sending the following JSON:

```
{"Profile":{"Id":-1,"Name":"New Profiledsa","IsOutlet":false,"IsWholesaler":false,"IsProducer":false,"Localizations":null},"LanguageCode":"en","Description":"Description for selected language","__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"Profile.Id":true,"Profile.Name":true,"Profile.IsOutlet":true,"Profile.IsWholesaler":true,"Profile.IsProducer":true,"Profile.Localizations":true,"Profile":true,"LanguageCode":true,"Description":true},"copiedProperties":{}}}
```

Which gets parsed by Chrome like:

[image]

And on the server, when I try to receive a `ProfileLocalizationViewModel`, the values received are all null:

[image]

Any idea why this happens? Any advice greatly appreciated.

Client ajax call:

```
self.saveProfile = function (model, event) {
    model.ItemForEditing.LanguageCode = self.SelectedLanguage.Code().toLowerCase();
    var preview = ko.toJSON(model.ItemForEditing);
    if (validateForm()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlSaveProfile,
            data: ko.toJSON(model.ItemForEditing),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () 
            success: function (result) {
                // Handle the response here.
                self.pushProfile(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Data));
                addContainer.modal('hide');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And inside `preview`, right before the call, there's the JSON...

[image]

Comment: Can you show the script/code that executes the post on the browser?

Comment: Try using ProfileViewModel profile instead of ProfileLocalizationViewModel profile.

Comment: @Igor added client side

Comment: @Kami I managed to receive the `ProfileViewModel`, but what I need is the `ProfileLocalizationViewModel`, which contains a `ProfileViewModel` plus extra stuff.

Comment: If your telling jqury to send json you don't need to encode it yourself, jquery does this when you pass it an object. you'll be double encoding the data. So remove ko.toJSON. If you check this on the wire (using something like fiddler) you should be able to see the issue.

Comment: Additionally to Liam's comment try adding dataType: "json" in the ajax call.

Comment: Removing the ko.toJSON results in the error `Invalid JSON primitive: Profile.` on the server, and the request payload looks like `Profile%5BId%5D=-1&Profile%5BName%5D=New+Profiledsa&`. Also tried the dataType, doesn't seem to affect anything..

Comment: I would do a little trial and error but keep it basic. Start by passing in a hard coded json string that contains the 2 primitive properties to the data and see if that works. Try tweaking the variable names/object and also the dataType until you get that to come across OK. Then expand it with your profile object property. Once that all works and you know what you should be passing to data replace it with `ko.toJson` call on your object and make sure the translation is what you expect to be sent. Also on the server method you might have to add an attribute [FromBody] if its a webapi controller